# Cast in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, casting

I am having a problem with executing one SQL query, Below is my stored procedure

**Query**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ProcName
(
     @iID VARCHAR(50),
     @AccountID INT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = 'DELETE FROM ReferringPhysician WHERE iID IN(' + @iID + ') AND AccountID = '+ @AccountID + ''
EXEC (@Sql)
```

I am trying to execute this query but it gives me error because i am using `exec()`, Here in my where condition i am dealing with the `string`, and in another condition i am dealing with the `int`, so in second condition i am getting **casting error!** how can i get through this?

Any help is greatly Appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This looks like it would be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You should be using sp_executesql

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes but you can't pass a comma-separated list into sp_executesql and have it parse correctly as desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is susceptible to SQL injection.

One way to avoid the data type problem you are having is to pass proper data types where you can and not use `EXEC()` ([more details here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'DELETE dbo.referringPhysician
    WHERE iID IN (' + @iID + ') AND AccountID = @AccountID;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@AccountID INT', @AccountID;
```

You can completely protect this from SQL injection by using table-valued parameters and passing in a DataTable or other collection with proper types instead of a comma-delimited string. e.g.:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.iIDs TABLE(iID INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Now your stored procedure can avoid dynamic SQL altogether:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ProcName -- always use schema prefix!
  @iIDs dbo.iIDs READONLY,
  @AccountID INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DELETE r
    FROM dbo.ReferringPhysician AS r
    INNER JOIN @iIDs AS i
    ON r.iID = i.iID
    WHERE r.AccountID = @AccountID;
END
GO
```

Comment: AccountID is an INT type. It's actually the @iID parameter (varchar(50)) that's most vulnerable.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes true. But you can't fix that with just sp_executesql. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand So, you want to say that i don't have to pass comma delimited strings to my stored procedure. right?

Comment: @The-Val yes, that's right, you shouldn't be converting sets to comma-separated strings just to do the reverse inside of SQL Server. It's a set, treat it as a set, always. Don't try to force SQL Server to become fluent in JSON.

Comment: Okk! Thanks for your time @AaronBertrand, i greatly appreciate your support! Learnt a new thing today. Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ProcName
(
     @iID VARCHAR(50),
     @AccountID INT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = 'DELETE FROM ReferringPhysician WHERE iID IN(' + CAST(@iID AS VARCHAR) + ') AND AccountID = '+ CAST(@AccountID AS VARCHAR) + ''
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Comment: Please [don't use varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: No need to cast `@iID` as `VARCHAR` since it is defined as one already. And please, always use length with the `VARCHAR` (as in `VARCHAR(50)`

Comment: Not sure why this is down-voted. It solves the problem even if it's not the most optimal solution.